# How can we make this site better?

Tags: discussion

We have currently spent 32 days in beta.  In that time, we have attracted more people to participate, asked some good questions, and had some good answers.  Unfortunately, by the standards of the Stack Exchange, we need [some work](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics).

In order for this exchange to succeed, what can we do better?  What can we (cooperatively and individually) do to enhance and further the site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [30 dias in Beta - We Need More Questions](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/30-dias-in-beta-we-need-more-questions)